# SQL join to return a table with multiple columns from other tables replacing its own

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, join

I am trying to write an SQL query that will return Table1, which has 10 columns. This table consists of a primary key id, 4 foreign key Id columns, and 5 other columns that I want to return but not change. The goal is to do a join to replace the foreign key Ids with their descriptions that are held in other tables.

Here is one attempt with the first FK Id:

```
Select * from Table1 t1
            left join Table2 t2
            on t1.BranchId = t2.BranchId;
```

This left join returns the description from table2, but does not replace it.

Here is another with the first FK Id:

```
Select t2.BranchName from Table1 t1
            left join Table2 t2
            on t1.BranchId = t2.BranchId;
```

This returns the name I want, but does not return table1 fully.

For the sake of an example you could pretend that OtherName3, OtherName4, OtherName5 are in tables Table3, Table4, Table5, respectively.

This may seem trivial for experienced SQL devs, but I am having a hard time figuring out the syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "replace it"?

Comment: Specify each column you want explicitly: `select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t3.col2 ...`

Comment: As in replace `BranchId` from Table1 with its name from table2 when table2 consists of the id and its name

Comment: Both Gordon's and my answer should be exactly what you need, with some massaging from you on the actual column names.

Comment: Okay, I'll try them out. Looks like what I'm referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by 'replace' but you just need to qualify what columns from which table you want.  That goes for all tables you are joined to, especially if they have the same column name in multiple tables.  I put junk columns in since I don't know your tables but you should get the general idea.

```
Select t2.BranchName, t1.BranchId, t1.Name, t1.Amount, t2.BranchLocation from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2
on t1.BranchId = t2.BranchId;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by replace it.

I think you just need to list out all the columns you want:

```
Select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, . . .,
       t2.name
from Table1 t1 left join
     Table2 t2
     on t1.BranchId = t2.BranchId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select t1.*, t2.BranchName from Table1 t1
            left join Table2 t2
            on t1.BranchId = t2.BranchId;
```

Return Table1 fully (all columns) and only the description (BranchName) from Table2.

If using SQL Server, see all syntax options for the SELECT clause here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx